# What is the meaning of Library not loaded?

Tags: macos, centos7, gate

I installed a simulation software on macOS Mojave, but when I run it by command, it shows the following response:

```
goldans-mac-pro:~ goldan$ Gate
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libG4Tree.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/goldan/GATE/Gate-8.2-install/bin/Gate
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I also installed same software on our centOS 7 system, but it is ok without this problem, does anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the software can run on macOS? It is missing `libG4Tree.dylib` file  - the macOS version of the G4Tree library...